# Where does currently fit in?

Tags: grammaticality

There are currently no employees assigned to this work center. 
or 
There are no employees currently assigned to this work center.

Comment: They're both OK. You can even say "Currently, there are no employees assigned to this work center."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adverb sentence query](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445964/adverb-sentence-query) It's ambiguous in the example above whether ***currently*** syntactically modifies the relevant verb (***are***, in this particular construction, ***assigned*** if rephrased to *no employees **currently** assigned*). It can equally be seen as a "whole sentence adverb" - this is a *syntactic* issue that doesn't really affect the meaning.